# When trying to use a rq worker get rq.exceptions.DeserializationError

Tags: django, rq

When trying to run `django-rq` worker I keep getting this error

```
15:35:26 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 249, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 2141, in model_unpickle
    model = apps.get_model(*model_id)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 1026, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 911, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 284, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 252, in _deserialize_data
    raise DeserializationError() from e
rq.exceptions.DeserializationError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 249, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 2141, in model_unpickle
    model = apps.get_model(*model_id)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 1026, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 911, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 284, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/api.to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 252, in _deserialize_data
    raise DeserializationError() from e
rq.exceptions.DeserializationError
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that I was trying to run `rqworker files` instead of `python manage.py rqworker files`